# Error 403 while trying to log into a website for scraping the content

Tags: python, web-scraping, python-requests, request

The goal is to get access to the subsciption-based content of the website.
I am trying to post my user/pass to https://www.ukwhoswho.com/ and get access to the (un)locked content.
Please note that the log-in box that I should use is the one within the website (to the left) NOT the "Personal Profile" on top right of the screen.

I have used the code below but I cannot log-in, can anyone please tell me what I am doing wrong?

```
import requests
params = {'user':username, 'pass':password}
headers = {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/56.0.2924.76 Safari/537.36'} # This is chrome, you can set whatever browser you like
r = requests.post('https://www.ukwhoswho.com/LOGIN', data=params, headers=headers)
r
```

I have also tried it using the one below but I still get the same error.

```
import requests

post_url = 'https://www.ukwhoswho.com/LOGIN'

client = requests.session()
r = client.get('https://www.ukwhoswho.com/')

header_info = {
"Host": "www.ukwhoswho.com",
"User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64; rv:107.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/107.0",
"Accept": "text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/avif,image/webp,*/*;q=0.8",
"Accept-Language": "en-US,en;q=0.5",
"Accept-Encoding": "gzip, deflate, br",
"Content-Type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded",
"Content-Length": "39",
"Origin": "https://www.ukwhoswho.com",
"DNT": "1",
"Connection": "keep-alive",
"Referer": "https://www.ukwhoswho.com/"
}

payload = {'user':username, 'pass':password} 

r = client.post(post_url, data=payload, headers = header_info)

print(r.text)
print(r.status_code)
```

Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: Have you looked at the entire contents of the POST request using the dev tools when you log in via your browser? It looks like the form is being passed through a JavaScript validation function first, and there's at least one hidden field in the form that I see, there may be more.

Comment: Sorry I am new to this, I cannot find where else "POST" is sending my credentials to. Can you please tell me if I am right based on the screenshot attached? https://ibb.co/vBCjXwW

Comment: @MattDMo Other "POST"s are as follows:

region1.google-analytics.com//g/collect type:plain
www.google-analytics.com/j/collect type:plain
apm.oupprodelk.pubfactory.com/intake/v2/rum/events type:xml
region1.google-analytics.com/g/collect type: plain

Comment: Yeah, I think you have the right POST in your screenshot. The other ones you mentioned are most likely trackers.